# Can`t retrieve specific json data with ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

im a beginer, i have a problem with my code, i cant pick up the specific data from my json with ajax and show it in my input text.

if i do $("#gakubuText").val(data.gakubu); doesnt work but if i do
$("#gakubuText").val(data); it`s work

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8080/mvcsi/public/gakubu/getUpdate',
        data:{id:id},
        method:'post',
        type:'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
```

//problem-> 
                $("#gakubuText").val(data.gakubu);

```
        }

    });
```

this is my input text in modal box

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="gakubuText" value=""  placeholder="学部名" required>
```

this is the data from my console

```
{"code_gakubu":"8","gakubu":"AAA"}
```

Comment: both $("#gakubuText").val(data.gakubu); are identical

Comment: Well I don't see why your code should not work,what exactly does `it doesn't work` mean for you? What is the result of `$("#gakubuText").val()` after the ajax call?

Comment: it mean i cant show the data to my input text(no value)

Comment: if i do $("#gakubuText").val(data) its showing all of my json data ->{"code_gakubu":"8","gakubu":"AAA"} to my input text

Comment: if i selecting a spesific data like $("#gakubuText").val(data.gakubu) it doesnt show the data to the input text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need Javascript object, but from server you get JSON. Try to use

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

This will transform JSON into plain object that you can access as data.gakubu